# Moment validations work only on some devices in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, momentjs

I have the following code in my React Native application.

```
const year10To18 = (val) => {
  const birthDate = moment(new Date(val));
  const today = moment();
  const difference = today.diff(birthDate, 'years');
  return difference >= 10 && difference <= 18;
};
```

This validation works properly on my android device, but in other devices, this doesn't work? What can be the issue here?

NOTE: I found out the issue. If the React Native debugger is on, then the validation works properly. But without that, the validation doesn't work.

Don't know the reason yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by different JavaScript Environments. Look at the docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html):

> ## JavaScript Runtime
>
> When using React Native, you're going to be running your JavaScript
> code in two environments:
>
> - In most cases, React Native will use JavaScriptCore, the JavaScript engine that powers Safari. Note that on iOS, JavaScriptCore
>   does not use JIT due to the absence of writable executable memory in
>   iOS apps.
> - When using Chrome debugging, all JavaScript code runs within Chrome itself, communicating with native code via WebSockets. Chrome
>   uses V8 as its JavaScript engine.
>
> While both environments are very similar, you may end up hitting some
> inconsistencies. We're likely going to experiment with other
> JavaScript engines in the future, so it's best to avoid relying on
> specifics of any runtime.

I think the problem might be the date creation. Instead of `new Date(val)`, try to create a date directy with moment. For example:  `moment(2019-30-06, "YYYY-DD-MM")`